# How to fix missing DataKeys in Viewstate when using custom PageStatePersister

Tags: c#, webforms, session-state

We have a website using Webforms. We want to use a custom PageStatePersister which saves the viewstate into a redis cache (see code below).  On page level we override the PageStatePersister property to use our PageStatePersister. All works fine so far, but when we have a control within another control, we encounter a few issues.

```cs
   public class RedisPageStatePersister : PageStatePersister
    {
        const string ViewStateFieldName = "__VIEWSTATEKEY";
        const string ViewStateKeyPrefix = "ViewState_";

        public RedisPageStatePersister(Page page) : base(page)
        {
        }



        public override void Load()
        {
            var key = Page.UniqueID;


            // The cache key for this viewstate is stored in a hidden field, so grab it
            string viewStateKey = Page.Request.Form[ViewStateFieldName] as string;

            // Grab the viewstate data using the key to look it up
            if (viewStateKey != null)
            {
                var database = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase(1);

                var viewstate = database.StringGet(viewStateKey);

                if (!viewstate.IsNull)
                {
                    Pair p = (Pair)StateFormatter.Deserialize(database.StringGet(viewStateKey));

                    ViewState = p.First;
                    ControlState = p.Second;
                }
            }
        }

        public override void Save()
        {
            string viewStateKey = Page.Request.Form[ViewStateFieldName] as string;

            if (viewStateKey == null)
            {
                viewStateKey = ViewStateKeyPrefix + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }

            // Put viewstate data on writer
            var viewStateSerialized = StateFormatter.Serialize(new Pair(base.ViewState, base.ControlState));

            // Store the viewstate's key in a hidden field, so on postback we can grab it from the cache
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField(ViewStateFieldName, viewStateKey);

            // Get the Redis database
            var database = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase(1);

            // Save viewstate to the database
            database.StringSet(viewStateKey, viewStateSerialized, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
        }
    }
```

For example:

- When using ListViews. We have a ListView with DataKeys within another ListView. On postback, the datakeys are not restored for the nested ListView

```html
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvOuter" DataKeyNames="These,Keys,Work">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvInner" DataKeyNames="These,Keys,Dont,Work">
                <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

- We use dynamic creates TabPanel with GridView within. The GridView within loose their datakeys values on postback

The problem only seems to encounter for DataKeys, the use of HiddenField for example is no problem.

I also tried to use the SessionPageStatePersister, since this is a built-in persister, but here too the problem occurs

Below a code snippet where dummy data is bound to a listview and its inner listview. The error occurs when clicking on the button and trying to retrieve the datakey values of the inner listview. The property "DataKeys" is an empty list, so a IndexOutOfRangeException is thrown.

```cs
    public partial class InnerListViewTest : Page
    {
        public class Outer
        {
            public List<Inner> Inner { get; set; }

            public string Key1 { get; set; }

            public string Key2 { get; set; }
        }

        public class Inner
        {
            public string InnerKey1 { get; set; }
            public string InnerKey2 { get; set; }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var data = new List<Outer>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    data.Add(new Outer()
                    {
                        Inner = new List<Inner>()
                        {
                            new Inner() {
                                InnerKey1 = "InnerData1_" + i,
                                InnerKey2 = "InnerData2_" + i
                            },
                            new Inner() {
                                InnerKey1 = "InnerData3_" + i,
                                InnerKey2 = "InnerData4_" + i
                            },
                            new Inner() {
                                InnerKey1 = "InnerData5_" + i,
                                InnerKey2 = "InnerData6_" + i
                            }
                        },
                        Key1 = "Data1_" + i,
                        Key2 = "Data2_" + i
                    });
                }

                lvOuter.DataSource = data;
                lvOuter.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void lvOuter_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            var outerData = e.Item.DataItem as Outer;

            var lvInner = e.Item.FindControl("lvInner") as ListView;
            lvInner.DataSource = outerData.Inner;
            lvInner.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem outerItem in lvOuter.Items)
            {
                var lvInner = outerItem.FindControl("lvInner") as ListView;

                foreach (ListViewItem innerItem in lvInner.Items)
                {
                    var innerKey1 = lvInner.DataKeys[innerItem.DataItemIndex]["InnerKey1"];
                    var innerKey2 = lvInner.DataKeys[innerItem.DataItemIndex]["InnerKey2"];

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is probably with the pagepersister, but i cant seem to find out why!

Answer (score 1):

I already found my own answer! The PageStatePersister had to be enabled using a PageAdapter instead of overriding the property of the Page!